# How to build ffmpeg in Android NDK under Windows

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm trying to build ffmpeg in Android NDK under Windows to put into an app but having issues.
I found various guides on how to do this but they were all many years old and no longer worked.

What I've done so far is install NDK and downloaded the latest ffmpeg 3.1.2 source code into the sources folder. I also installed cygwin.

I then created a script, build_android.sh, with the code (taken from another guide):

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=/cygdrive/c/Android/ndk/android-ndk-r12b
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-24/arch-arm64/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64
function build_one
{
    ./configure \
   --prefix=$PREFIX \
   --disable-shared \
   --enable-static \
   --disable-doc \
   --disable-ffmpeg \
   --disable-ffplay \
   --disable-ffprobe \
   --disable-ffserver \
   --disable-avdevice \
   --disable-doc \
   --disable-symver \
   --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
   --target-os=linux \
   --arch=arm \
   --enable-cross-compile \
   --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
   --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
   --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
   $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make
make install
}
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU 
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
build_one
```

When I run this I get:

```
Makefile:198: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
```

Anyone know how to successfully build ffmpeg in NDK or have any guides that work with the latest version?

Thanks,
Oliver

Answer (score 1):

"tests" is a subfolder in the ffmpeg folder. It is required for build, but it looks like it is missing. Ensure you've pulled down the entire ffmpeg source tree.

Your build_android.sh looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks for your response
That was actually the first thing I checked, the tests sub-folder and Makefile both exist under the ffmpeg source folder but strangely when building it gives the message that it can't find it

Comment: I notice that it's looking for "tests" in the root. I would've expected it to say "No rule to make target 'tests/Makefile'" instead. Can you edit the "make install" line to include the "--debug=v" switch, and relate some of the output? You might also edit line 198 of ffmpeg/Makefile to point explicitly at the correct tests folder, until we figure this out.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I took a look at Makefile line 198 - the line is:
    include $(SRC_PATH)/tests/Makefile
So it looks like SRC_PATH isn't set. I tried setting it in build_android.sh but it had no affect. Do you know how I should set this?

Comment: SRC_PATH is set by the ./configure script (from build_android.sh). It echoes it to the screen as the second line of output ("source path"). On mine, "source path" is ".". How does your ./configure output look? Did it throw any errors? In some cases, if the ffmpeg full path has a space in it, the build will fail.

Comment: I've managed to get a very close to getting it building by changing the directory from /cygdrive/c/ to c:/ which seemed to get it building. I also added --enable-jni and changed target os to android.

But now after a while of compilation I get:
ffserver.c: In function ‘main’:
ffserver.c:4003:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘sigaction’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sigact, 0);

Any idea how to fix that? I might look into just disabling the ffserver component as I don't think I need it just for what I want to do

Comment: Looks like you've got some sort of #include problem. signal.h comes with Cygwin, and it declares sigaction(). Not sure why it wouldn't work for you. There weren't any errors prior to that?

Comment: I realised that I lost the backslashes in the configure command which meant none of the arguments were being used. Once I put these back in this error disappeared but I'm now seeing:    libavutil/libavutil.so:1:1: syntax error, unexpected '!', expecting $end      
error: libavutil/libavutil.so: not an object or archive
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Try adding more of the build output to your question. You're pretty deep in the weeds here, by which I mean you are seeing things that really shouldn't be happening. I recommend starting again with your original files, and, using what you've learned, alter 1 thing at a time, seeing what works best. Incidentally, you can safely delete all the .so files, as these are a build output. The "make clean" should already be doing that, but just to be sure...

Comment: Had a go starting again from scratch and found several alternative build scripts but each one had issues. I think I'm going to give up on this for now. Perhaps at some point I'll try building it in Ubuntu rather than Windows, maybe that'll have more luck